# How come this code is throwing a nullpointerexception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I do not understand why this code throws a **null pointer exception** because I thought line 3 sets the value of `sampleArray[0][0])` to `1`.

```
int arrSize = 100;
String[][] sampleArray = new String[arrSize][];
sampleArray[0][0]="1";
System.out.println(sampleArray[0][0]);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sampleArray[0]` has not been initialized as an array. 
You initialized the first dimension of the array, but not the second one

You would need to do something like `sampleArray[0] = new String[size]`

The initializer `String[][] sampleArray = new String[arrSize][]` works because you are creating an array that has references to other arrays. Each one of those other arrays can have a different size which you can set as you wish. What I mean is that the following would be perfectly legal:

`sampleArray[0] = new String[10];
 sampleArray[1] = new String[5];
 System.out.println(sampleArray[0][9]);
 System.out.println(sampleArray[1][4]);`

Comment: Please see my comment to mtefi answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set only the first dimension's size of a 2d array. Because it's an array of arrays, so you can't get back an array of not instantiated arrays.

Comment: OK the code works if  I change line 2 to: 
String[][] sampleArray = new String[arrSize][10];

Does that mean I always have to set the size of both the first dimension and second dimension?

But what I don't understand is why is this still a valid initializer:
String[][] sampleArray = new String[100][];

Comment: It is equal to String[] sampleArray = new String[100].. when you instantiate an array, you have to give it it's size. Try using ArrayList<String[]> instead if you would like to add different sized arrays to an array, it's more clean.